# XSLT to pick specific nodes, and parameterizing it from Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML structure like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
    <PackageHeader>yadda yadda </PackageHeader>
     <PackageBody>
      <Element1>foo</Element1>
      <Element2>bar</Element2>
      <ElementN>xyz</ElementN>
   </PackageBody>
```

I have a requirement where I need to eliminate either Element1, Element2, or ElementN, so I wrote this XSLT,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::Element1)][not(self::Element2)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

I am running this via a simple Java XSL Transformation program. The transformed XML has only elevrything from the orignal XML minus Element1 & Element2. I tried many ways to pass parameters from the Java program to parameterize which nodes should be eliminated, but no luck so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a task for XSLT 3 with static parameters and shadow attributes, best used with the Saxon s9api if that is the processor used.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a task for XSLT 3 with static parameters and shadow attributes, best used with the Saxon s9api (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/javadoc/index.html) if that is the processor used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="element-to-be-removed" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'Element2'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template _match="{$element-to-be-removed}"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaiE